# How to extract a frame (substring) from the group of frames

Tags: regex

I've frames in long sting like that:

```
CCadad6876adDDCCdashajdhakdhadhDDCCsfjskfjsklfjDDCClskfjlsdfjDD
```

The frames are grouped between `CC` and `DD`. So the example above present three frames.

```
CCadad6876adDD
CCdashajdhakdhadhDD
CCsfjskfjsklfjDD
CClskfjlsdfjDD
```

I'd like to extract the frames from this long string to the form presented just above. To do this I've used expression:

```
CC[a-zA-Z0-9]+DD
```

hoping to catch first frame within the string.

However, instead of having expected `CCadad6876adDD` the whole string was matched. The match is right as the `CCadad6876adDDCCdashajdhakdhadhDDCCsfjskfjsklfjDDCClskfjlsdfjDD` start and finishes with `CC` and `DD` as well, but how to insist the regex to focus on the first frame?.

What shall I modify in RegEx to catch first frame?

Comment: for a regex question, please always add the information which tool/programming language are you using. since there are different regex flavors.

Comment: you just need to add `?` after `+`. For more info , see the link which shows on your question.

Comment: Which language are you using ? You need to set the regex parameter to match minimal (first match found) in the language you are using ..

Answer (score 1):

You missed to specify the programming language, here comes an example in PHP:

```
$string = <<<EOF 
CCadad6876adDD
CCdashajdhakdhadhDD
CCsfjskfjsklfjDD
CClskfjlsdfjDD
EOF;

preg_match_all('/CC.*?DD/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

*Output:*

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "CCadad6876adDD"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "CCdashajdhakdhadhDD"
    [2]=>
    string(16) "CCsfjskfjsklfjDD"
    [3]=>
    string(14) "CClskfjlsdfjDD"
  }
}
```